# Mental health diagnosis datasets?

Tags: machine-learning

What I am looking for is a dataset that has a number of independent variables, such as age, sex, smoker/non-smoker etc. for which I intend to carry out supervised learning for the dependent variable which would be a mental health diagnosis such as major depression, schizophrenia or a personality disorder.

I am aware of the SAMHDA data on drug abuse but that is not quite what I am looking for.

(I do not have institutional access to any such thing.)

Answer (score 3):

nsduh is publicly-downloadable http://www.asdfree.com/2012/11/analyze-national-survey-on-drug-use-and.html

Comment: probably should edit your question to clarify why nsduh doesn't have whatcha need

Comment: That was in there from the beginning: "I am aware of the SAMHDA data on drug abuse but that is not quite what I am looking for."

Comment: Also: "I intend to carry out supervised learning for the dependent variable which would be a mental health diagnosis such as major depression, schizophrenia or a personality disorder." All of these may be comorbid with some sort of drug abuse but are not issues of drug abuse per se.

Comment: nsduh has these variables.  please edit your question to explain why they're not suitable for you, thanks